# Write Junit Test for ServiceMix web-service

Tags: rest, junit, apache-servicemix

I am used to using Spring and writing Spring RESTful web-services.  I have no problem writing Spring Controllers, passing in data and then verifying getting back the correct JSON data.

Now, I have a new job and they deploy RESTful web-services to ServiceMix 4.5 as OSGI jars.

The method that I have has a definition like:

```
   @GET
   @Path("myWebService")  
   @Trace
   @Override    
   @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
   @WebResult(name="isDuplicate")
   public MyResponse myWebService(@QueryParam("field1") final String field1, @QueryParam("fieldData") final String fieldData) throws SOAPException  
   {
       final Session session = BundleActivator.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
       Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();

       Boolean retVal = new SimpleTransaction<Boolean, Void>()
       {
           @Override
           public Boolean execute(Void nothing)
           {                   
               Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(tableName);

               try
               {
                    // some logic here   
               }
               catch (JSONException e1)
               {
                   throw new RuntimeException(e1.getMessage());
               }

               List<Object> recordList = (List<Object>)criteria.list();
               if(recordList.size()  > 0)
               {
                   return true;
               }

               return false;
           }

       }.run(transaction, null);

   }
}
```

This isn't all of the code, but it's very close.

So, I need to do something similar like I do with my Spring Unit tests.
Without knowing all the deep details, I know that I load the Spring Application Context, and then I make a mockrequest to the RESTful web-service passing in my verbs (GET, POST, PUT DELETE) with the right json data, and then I get back the mock http response.

When I used Google to search for how to test a Spring MVC RESTful web-services, I could easily find all types of examples on this.  When I do the same for ServiceMix OSGI web-services, I don't find much.  So, I am looking for examples or url's that I can approach and look at.

If I need to provide any more information, please let me know.

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the link in which we are testing the camel route using CamelTestSupport, modify the endpoint which is web service url in your case.

http://www.softwarepassion.com/servicemix-fuseesb-unit-testing-your-routes/